# Using Where and group by clause

Tags: sql, group-by, where-clause

Can anyone describe how can I suppose to retrieve data using filter conditions such as both where and `group by` clauses of different fields through SQL ?

For instance ,

Require to take out the No of days in a month does the temperature exceeding 35 degrees celsius ?

```
SELECT temp, count(*) 
FROM weather_data 
WHERE  day between '01-jun-2022' to '30-jun-2022' 
GROUP BY temp > '35';
```

My requirement is to find out the aggregate details like total count
So I tried using group by clause , Inaddition to that , I must use few conditions to filter further ,
Hence I used conditions in where clause before group by clause

Comment: Please read this https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example and follow the instructions.

Comment: What is your DBMS? It can be very important to know this in order to give you an answer that works for you. Always tag your SQL requests with your DBMS.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
SELECT temp, count(*)
FROM weather_data
WHERE date >= '01-jun-2022' AND date<='30-jun-2022' AND temp > '35'
GROUP BY temp;
```

Answer (score 0):

it's correct query :

```
SELECT temp, count(*) FROM weather_data 
WHERE temp > '35' AND day between '01-jun-2022' and '30-jun-2022' GROUP BY temp
```

Comment: No, it's not. Better try out queries before showing them.

Answer (score 0):

You want to aggregate your data, so as to get one result row per month. In SQL this is `GROUP BY EXTRACT(YEAR FROM day), EXTRACT(MONTH FROM day)`. Your DBMS may have additional functions to extract  a month (year + month to be precise) from a date, such as `TO_CHAR(day, 'YYYY-MM')`, but this is vendor specific.

Now you only want to count days with a temperature obove 35 degrees. The first idea to solve this, is a `WHERE` clause that limits the rows you aggregate to the ones in question:

```
SELECT
  EXTRACT(YEAR FROM day) AS year,
  EXTRACT(MONTH FROM day) AS month,
  COUNT(*)
FROM mytable
WHERE temp > 35
GROUP BY EXTRACT(YEAR FROM day), EXTRACT(MONTH FROM day)
ORDER BY EXTRACT(YEAR FROM day), EXTRACT(MONTH FROM day);
```

The problem with this: If a month has no day above that temperature, you won't select that month, because your `WHERE` clause removed those rows. That may be okay with you, but if you want to show the months with a zero count, then move the condition into the aggregation function. Thus you select all months but only count days with high temperatures:

```
SELECT
  EXTRACT(YEAR FROM day) AS year,
  EXTRACT(MONTH FROM day) AS month,
  COUNT(CASE WHEN temp > 35 THEN 1 END)
FROM mytable
GROUP BY EXTRACT(YEAR FROM day), EXTRACT(MONTH FROM day)
ORDER BY EXTRACT(YEAR FROM day), EXTRACT(MONTH FROM day);
```

How does this work? `COUNT <expression> )` counts non-null occurrences. `CASE WHEN temp > 35 THEN 1 END` is short for `CASE WHEN temp > 35 THEN 1 ELSE NULL END`. And instead of 1 you could use any value that is not null, e.g. 'count me'. Or you could use `SUM` instead, if you like that better: `SUM(CASE WHEN temp > 35 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END)`.

At last you want to limit the date range. Date literals in SQL look like this: `DATE 'YYYY-MM-DD'`. And as we sometimes deal with dates and other times with datetimes or timestamps, it has become common, not to use `BETWEEN`, but `>=` and `<`, so as to have the range work for all those data types:

```
SELECT
  EXTRACT(YEAR FROM day) AS year,
  EXTRACT(MONTH FROM day) AS month,
  COUNT(CASE WHEN temp > 35 THEN 1 END)
FROM mytable
WHERE day >= DATE '2022-06-01'
  AND day <  DATE '2022-07-01'
GROUP BY EXTRACT(YEAR FROM day), EXTRACT(MONTH FROM day)
ORDER BY EXTRACT(YEAR FROM day), EXTRACT(MONTH FROM day);
```